# Properly nesting loops with Python3 for a stepper motor

Tags: python, loops, raspberry-pi, nested

I'm trying to operate a stepper motor using a Raspberry Pi and adafruit Motor HAT, in order to turn a rod which lifts small water-filled pots. However I need to do this in slow stages, to allow water to drain out and prevent the system being too heavy for the motor.

I am trying to create a nested loop which performs a discrete number of steps, pauses for a period, then performs the loop again. I am having difficulty with pause element, as my attempts at nesting end up turning the motor off after the first rotation.

I can simulate the effect I want to achieve using the code below, but it is obviously bulky, inefficient and difficult to precisely fix the number of loops.

```
from adafruit_motorkit import MotorKit
from time import sleep

kit = MotorKit()

from adafruit_motor import stepper

for i in range(20):
        kit.stepper1.onestep(direction=stepper.BACKWARD, style=stepper.INTERLEAVE)

print("Turn")

sleep(10)

for i in range(20):
        kit.stepper1.onestep(direction=stepper.BACKWARD, style=stepper.INTERLEAVE)

print("Turn")

sleep(10)

for i in range(20):
        kit.stepper1.onestep(direction=stepper.BACKWARD, style=stepper.INTERLEAVE)

print("Turn")

for i in range(20):
        kit.stepper1.onestep(direction=stepper.BACKWARD, style=stepper.INTERLEAVE)

print("Turn")

sleep(10)

for i in range(20):
        kit.stepper1.onestep(direction=stepper.BACKWARD, style=stepper.INTERLEAVE)

print("Turn")

sleep(10)

for i in range(20):
        kit.stepper1.onestep(direction=stepper.BACKWARD, style=stepper.INTERLEAVE)

print("Turn")
```

I would be very grateful for advice on how to properly nest the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below should do exactly what you have got

```py
from adafruit_motorkit import MotorKit
from time import sleep

kit = MotorKit()

from adafruit_motor import stepper
for j in range(6):
    for i in range(20):
        kit.stepper1.onestep(direction=stepper.BACKWARD, style=stepper.INTERLEAVE)

    print("Turn %s" % (j + 1))

    sleep(10)
```

Comment: @James , no problem and welcome to Stack Overflow.  As a guide please see the following post regarding Accepted answers https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers